# How to find an object from array list

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, lodash

I have a list of all available stock items with a unique stock id and detail attributes. From the UI, I collect customer selection, based on the unique value code in customer selection, I would like to find the selected item from the stock items. That is,

What is the best approach to find **stockItem** from **availableStock** that matches the *value* code attribute in **customerSelection** array list? Please have a look at the example below:

```
const customerSelection = {
    "tv": [
        {
            "value": "tv_40",
            "label": "Flat Screen"
        }
    ],
    "keyboard": [
        {
            "value": "keyboard_40",
            "label": "Wireless Keyboard"
        }
    ],
    "mouse": [
        {
            "value": "mouse_40",
            "label": "Wireless Mouse"
        }
    ]
};
```

```
const availableStock = [
    {
        "stockId": "elec_c1_f1",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "label": "Flat Screen",
                "value": "tv_41"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Keyboard",
                "value": "keyboard_41"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Mouse",
                "value": "mouse_41"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "stockId": "elec_c1_f2",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "label": "Flat Screen",
                "value": "tv_40"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Keyboard",
                "value": "keyboard_40"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Mouse",
                "value": "mouse_40"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "stockId": "elec_c1_f3",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "label": "Flat Screen",
                "value": "tv_42"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Keyboard",
                "value": "keyboard_42"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Mouse",
                "value": "mouse_42"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Expected result with stockId (or Just the stockId)**

```
const stockItem = {
    "stockId": "elec_c1_f2",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "label": "Flat Screen",
            "value": "tv_40"
        },
        {
            "label": "Wireless Keyboard",
            "value": "keyboard_40"
        },
        {
            "label": "Wireless Mouse",
            "value": "mouse_40"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestion with/without lodash is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a `requiredValues` array, using  [`Array.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

This will look like:

```
[ "tv_40", "keyboard_40", "mouse_40" ]
```

We'd then use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find all stock items with every required value present in its attributes.

We'd use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), along with [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to ensure *every* required value is present in the item attributes.

This would return a list of the stock items.

We can then map to get a list of matching stock ids:

```js
const customerSelection = { "tv": [ { "value": "tv_40", "label": "Flat Screen" } ], "keyboard": [ { "value": "keyboard_40", "label": "Wireless Keyboard" } ], "mouse": [ { "value": "mouse_40", "label": "Wireless Mouse" } ] };

const availableStock = [ { "stockId": "elec_c1_f1", "attributes": [ { "label": "Flat Screen", "value": "tv_41" }, { "label": "Wireless Keyboard", "value": "keyboard_41" }, { "label": "Wireless Mouse", "value": "mouse_41" } ] }, { "stockId": "elec_c1_f2", "attributes": [ { "label": "Flat Screen", "value": "tv_40" }, { "label": "Wireless Keyboard", "value": "keyboard_40" }, { "label": "Wireless Mouse", "value": "mouse_40" } ] }, { "stockId": "elec_c1_f3", "attributes": [ { "label": "Flat Screen", "value": "tv_42" }, { "label": "Wireless Keyboard", "value": "keyboard_42" }, { "label": "Wireless Mouse", "value": "mouse_42" } ] } ]
    
// These values must be present in the attributes...
const requiredValues = Object.values(customerSelection).map(val => val[0].value);

// Use Array.filter() to find stock items that match _all_ required attributes...
const foundItems = availableStock.filter(item => {
    return requiredValues.every(value => item.attributes.find(attr => attr.value === value));
});

console.log('Found stockIds:', foundItems.map(({ stockId }) => stockId));
console.log('Found items:', foundItems);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could also do this without building the `requiredValues` array first and simply call .every() on the customerSelection array:

```js
const customerSelection = { "tv": [ { "value": "tv_40", "label": "Flat Screen" } ], "keyboard": [ { "value": "keyboard_40", "label": "Wireless Keyboard" } ], "mouse": [ { "value": "mouse_40", "label": "Wireless Mouse" } ] };
const availableStock = [ { "stockId": "elec_c1_f1", "attributes": [ { "label": "Flat Screen", "value": "tv_41" }, { "label": "Wireless Keyboard", "value": "keyboard_41" }, { "label": "Wireless Mouse", "value": "mouse_41" } ] }, { "stockId": "elec_c1_f2", "attributes": [ { "label": "Flat Screen", "value": "tv_40" }, { "label": "Wireless Keyboard", "value": "keyboard_40" }, { "label": "Wireless Mouse", "value": "mouse_40" } ] }, { "stockId": "elec_c1_f3", "attributes": [ { "label": "Flat Screen", "value": "tv_42" }, { "label": "Wireless Keyboard", "value": "keyboard_42" }, { "label": "Wireless Mouse", "value": "mouse_42" } ] } ]

const foundItems = availableStock.filter(item => {
    return Object.values(customerSelection).every(([{ value }]) => { 
        return item.attributes.find(attr => attr.value === value);
    });
});

console.log('Found stockIds:', foundItems.map(({ stockId }) => stockId));
console.log('Found items:', foundItems);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly get all keys from customer selection:

```
var values = Object.keys(customerSelection).map(element =>customerSelection[element][0].value)
```

Then get matchedAvailableValues by using this code:

```
var matchedAvailableValues = availableStock.filter(element => values.includes(element.attributes[0].value) ? {stockId:element.stockId,attributes:element.attributes} : false);
```

So your final code looks like this:

```
var values = Object.keys(customerSelection).map(element => customerSelection[element][0].value)
var matchedValues = availableStock.filter(element => values.includes(element.attributes[0].value) ? {stockId:element.stockId,attributes:element.attributes}:false);
```

Comment: thanks @onurkan Bakrirci, your suggestion results:
```
[
  {
    stockId: 'elec_c1_f2',
    attributes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```
which is close to what I wanted to achieve, would it be possible to extract the only object with all details of the attributes field? for now, I see ``Object``

Comment: If you use console.log() for see result, result will shown as an Object. You can see actual result by console.log(matchedValues[0])

Comment: I just noticed this solution returns multiple stock items if they partially matched with attributes in customer selection.

Comment: I can't clearly understand the problem. Can you give more information about problem?

Comment: If you add one more object to availableStock list and re-run the code, you will understand what I mean. 
{
        "stockId": "elec_c1_f4",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "label": "Flat Screen",
                "value": "tv_42"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Keyboard",
                "value": "keyboard_11"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Mouse",
                "value": "mouse_42"
            }
        ]
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use nested `for..in` loops to navigate both objects.

```js
const customerSelection = {
    "tv": [
        {
            "value": "tv_41",
            "label": "Flat Screen"
        }
    ],
    "keyboard": [
        {
            "value": "keyboard_40",
            "label": "Wireless Keyboard"
        }
    ],
    "mouse": [
        {
            "value": "mouse_40",
            "label": "Wireless Mouse"
        }
    ]
};
const availableStock = [
    {
        "stockId": "elec_c1_f1",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "label": "Flat Screen",
                "value": "tv_41"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Keyboard",
                "value": "keyboard_41"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Mouse",
                "value": "mouse_41"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "stockId": "elec_c1_f2",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "label": "Flat Screen",
                "value": "tv_40"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Keyboard",
                "value": "keyboard_40"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Mouse",
                "value": "mouse_40"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "stockId": "elec_c1_f3",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "label": "Flat Screen",
                "value": "tv_42"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Keyboard",
                "value": "keyboard_42"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wireless Mouse",
                "value": "mouse_42"
            }
        ]
    }
];

for (o in customerSelection)
for (p in availableStock)
for (q in availableStock[p].attributes) 
if (customerSelection[o][0].value==availableStock[p].attributes[q].value) console.log(availableStock[p].stockId);
```

Comment: Thanks @JMP, the code you suggested returns stockIds, elec_c1_f1, elec_c1_f2, & elec_c1_f2. But I was expecting only elec_c1_f2.

Comment: I changed the first item in `customerSelection` because my code returns a `stockId` for each item in `customerSelection` rather than assume they are all going to be in the same stock group.